# Why do sticky posts show in this menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus

The code below writes out a list of the most recent posts. However, it does not appear to be skipping over sticky posts although I'm using 'post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'). What am I missing?

```
<?php
$cat=get_cat_ID('top-menu'); 
$catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
$myquery = new WP_Query();
$myquery->query(array(
    'cat' => "-$cat,-$catHidden",
    'post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
));
$myrecentpostscount = $myquery->found_posts;

if ($myrecentpostscount > 0) 
{ ?>
<div><h4>Recent Posts</h4>
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_recent = get_post( $current_page );
$myrecentposts = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat,-$catHidden",'numberposts' => $cb2_recent_count));
foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post) {
    ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking a one underscore in parameter, it should be `post__not_in`.

Also the better way is to use `caller_get_posts` parameter (it will be deprecated and replaced with more aptly named `ignore_sticky_posts` in 3.1 that will do same thing) that will keep sticky posts in results if they fit, but will prevent them from jumping to the top.

See [Sticky Post Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Sticky_Post_Parameters) in Codex.